# Multiple for loops to combine indexes of two arrays

Tags: java

I know this will repeat names loop every time until it finishes numbers loop, but I don't know a way to do this, I want to get the index of first number and name and combine those together. // I'm new in programming thanks for your time.

```
    int numbers[] = {2, 5, 8, 9};
    String names[] = {"john", "steve", "eric", "dan"};
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0;j < names.length; j++){
                System.out.println(numbers[i] + names [j]);
            }}
```

I need it to be like this:

2 john 
5 steve 
8 eric 
9 dan

Comment: Where is the data coming from? For example: If you have a input mask where someone can enter the name and a number and the input is done four times, then you can loop over the input count "c" and access the fields with numbers[c] and names[c].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the same loop and the same index to print the number and name at the same position:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
{
    System.out.print(numbers[i] + names[i]);
}
```

The best way to go about planning the solution to such questions is to try to recognize any similarities between the outputted values. Here, both have the same index, which means we can use increasing value `i` to print values at the same index.

Comment: Thanks, didnt thought about this ahhh

Comment: `i < Math.min(numbers.length, names.length)` to be safe (in case the array lengths ever differ).

Comment: yeah now is more solid no need for try/catch, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if both arrays have the same lenght, you could just do the loop once and concatenate their contents like this:

```
int numbers[] = {2, 5, 8, 9};
String names[] = {"john", "steve", "eric", "dan"};
  for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
    System.out.println(numbers[i] + names [i]);
  };
```

Alternatively you could stack those 2 arrays into a single array with 2 dimensions:

```
String people [] [] = {
  {"2", "5", "8", "9"},
  {"john", "steve", "eric", "dan"}
};

for (int i = 0; i < people.length; i++){
  System.out.println(people[i][i]);
};
```

The only issue there is that you will have to perform 2 loops like in your question to associate the correct weight to the correct person if the numbers or the names arrays have different sizes, but for that I'd recommend using collections, its more intuitive and better to handle.

Comment: yes the first one was what i was looking for, it is pretty simple but idk why i complicated it ahh.